# Create a Seekbar WIDGET

Tags: android, android-studio, widget, android-widget, seekbar

I am wondering if there is a way to create a Seekbar (slider) widget for an app. I know how to create a Seekbar in my app activity but how can I change this Seekbar-value with a widget? I tried to find some information about it in the internet but I couldn't find anything. So I don't know if it is even possible to create Seekbar widgets...

In advance thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "widgets" you mean [app widgets](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html), `SeekBar` is not one of [the supported views that you can use in an app widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Do you know a different way how I could change a Seekbar value with a different kind of widget? @CommonsWare

Comment: @julie22: I do not know what you mean. You cannot show a `SeekBar` in an app widget. You are welcome to use two `Button` or `ImageButton` widgets to represent "increase" and "decrease" actions. Then, perhaps use an `ImageView` with different images to represent different levels.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Progressbar with custom style to show a progress value in your widget.